# How to access Object and Element in event handler

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

Is there a way to pass element and instance to event handler callback?

```
listNotes(key, value){
            this.allnotes.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.constructor.userNoteTemplate(key, value))
            this.totalNotes();
            let note = document.querySelector(`#note-${key}`);
            note.addEventListener("click", this.deleteNote.bind(this));
    }

deleteNote(){
        let instance = this;
        let element = ?// I want the element details also
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler is passed an [*event object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) that lets you access various information, among others [the element the handler is bound to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

```
deleteNote(event){
    let instance = this;
    let element = event.currentTarget;
}
```